# Не буферизованный ввод python

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как в консоли, при использовании python, сделать не буферизованный ввод.
Может есть для python библиотека типа ncurses.h (использовал на Си)?

Comment: А чем input() не нравится?

Comment: Мне нужен не буферизованный ввод, типа getch() в Си. А input() ожидает нажатия Enter после ввода с клавиатуры.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Python read a single character from the user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/510357/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую воспользоваться пакетом `getch` с PyPI:
`pip install getch`

Там приведён такой сценарий использования:

```
import getch
# ...
char = getch.getch() # User input, but not displayed on the screen
# or
char = getch.getche() # also displayed on the screen
```

Библиотека является кроссплатформенной.